# Transition maps for the exterior bundle

Tags: vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a n-manifold and $(E,\pi,M)$ a bundle over $M$ with fiber $E_{m}, m \in M$; let $(\phi_{\alpha,\beta})$ the transition maps and $(U_{\alpha})$ an open cover of $M$.

Then I define $(\Lambda^{k}E)_{m}=\Lambda^{k}E_{m}$ and I want to build the exterior bundle. I cannot understand what the lectures did:

He defined $$\Lambda^{k}\phi_{\alpha,\beta}(m): \Lambda^{k}E_{m} \rightarrow \Lambda^{k}E_{m}$$ as $$\Lambda^{k}(\phi_{\alpha,\beta})(\theta)(v_{1},...v_{k})=\theta(\phi_{\alpha,\beta}(m)v_{1},...,\phi_{\alpha,\beta}(m)v_{k})$$ and he then noticed that this is the family of the transition maps for the exterior bundle, i.e., $\cup_{m \in M} \Lambda^{k}E_{m}$. But I studied that the transition maps should be defined on $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}$, so what I am missing?

Comment: $\phi_{\alpha,\beta}$ is defined on $U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}$, so it follows that $\Lambda^k\phi_{\alpha,\beta}$ is too. Does your confusion stem from the fact that the left hand side of the final equation does not mention $m$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you! No...I'm getting confused because $\Lambda^{k}(\phi_{\alpha,\beta})$ is defined on $M$ but it acts on p-form and not on vectors! How is it supposed to be a transition map if it doesn't act on vectors...I mean it should be an isomorphism between ${m} \times K^{k} \rightarrow {m} \times K^{k}$, where $K$ is a field

Comment: What do you understand $\Lambda^kE_m$ to mean?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Is it the set of the p-form over $E_{m}$?

Comment: That is a vector space, its elements are vectors.

Comment: So a transition map acts on the fiber, right?

Comment: From what you've said, it seems like your lecturer is using 'transition map' to mean something other than it usually does. Regardless, I will answer your question for the definitions you've used in the question. First, $\Lambda^k\phi_{\alpha,\beta}$ is defined on $U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}$. Now, for any $m \in U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}$, $(\Lambda^k\phi_{\alpha,\beta})(m)$ is a map $\Lambda^kE_m \to \Lambda^kE_m$, i.e. $(\Lambda^k\phi_{\alpha,\beta})(m)$ acts on the fiber of $\Lambda^kE$ over the chosen point $m$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese So usually transition maps act on what?

Comment: If $\psi_{\alpha}:\pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha})\to U_{\alpha}\times\mathbb{R}^d$, $\psi_{\beta}:\pi^{-1}(U_{\beta})\to U_{\beta}\times\mathbb{R}^d$ are trivialisations, then $\psi_{\alpha}\circ\psi_{\beta}^{-1}:(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})\times\mathbb{R}^d\to(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})\times\mathbb{R}^d$ is given by $(x,v)\mapsto(x,g_{\alpha\beta}(x)v)$ where $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}\to GL(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the transition function. Your lecturer seems to be looking at $\psi_{\alpha}^{-1}\circ\psi_{\beta}:\pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})\to\pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})$ instead.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you! You've been very kind! So I should simply take $(\Lambda^{k}(\phi_{\alpha,\beta}))^{-1}$

Comment: No, that's not the same thing. Note that $(\psi_{\alpha}^{-1}\circ\psi_{\beta})^{-1} = \psi_{\beta}^{-1}\circ\psi_{\alpha} \neq \psi_{\alpha}\circ\psi_{\beta}^{-1}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese But then he stated  that we can use the bundle construction lemma using $\Lambda^{k}(\phi_{\alpha,\beta})$ and I can't understand how...

Comment: You will have to ask him. A good textbook reference for this material is Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. Lemma 10.6 (of the second edition) seems to be the result you are referring to.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese THank you! You've been very kind